# Include a view with javascript functionality

Tags: include, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I want to *@include* a view in my main view. The thing is I've wrote sοme `javascript` code to interact with that piece of code. Is there a way to *include* both `html` and `javascript` code, since for the second one I have to add `<script>` tag? I `@include` this view in many files so I don't want to hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

Here's three options of things you can do, but there are plenty more:

```
<html><body>

    <!-- A javascript to be added by a particular view-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
       @yield('in-view-javascript')
    </script>

    <!-- A javascript only files, no script tag-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
       @include('views._partials.javascript-1')
       @include('views._partials.javascript-2')
       @include('views._partials.javascript-3')
    </script>

    <!-- A javascript code with script tag-->
    @include('views._partials.javascript-code')

</body></html>
```

In views you can

```
@section('in-view-javascript')

    console.log('in-view-javascript');

@stop
```

Or you can include another javascript file here:

```
@section('in-view-javascript')

    @include('views._partials.javascript')

@stop
```

Your `javascript-1`, `javascript-2`, `javascript-3` would be just javascript without the `<script>` tag.

And `javascript-code` would be a full javascript code, including the tag.